# python maximum sum of elementwise multiplication of two arrays

Tags: python

if `a= np.array([1, 1, 1, 4])` and `b= np.array([1, 4, 1, 1])` I want to achieve maximum possible sum of multiplication of elements.

For example here: the maximum possible sum of product will be

```
a[3]*b[1] + a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*a[b] + a[2]*b[3]
```

Is there a function that do this

Comment: Are you sure that the example is true? There is no reference to `b`

Comment: There is no in-built function but you can sort one array in ascending order and the other in descending order and then find the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
np.dot(sorted(a), sorted(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by @NYCCoder, here is a solution using chained numpy methods:

```
max_sum_of_products = np.sort(np.stack([a, b])).prod(axis=0).sum()
print(max_sum_of_products)
```

```
19
```

Answer (score -1):

There's no single function to do this, but programming is all about breaking problems down. And you have two things you want to do.

1. Multiply each element pairwise
2. Find the maximum

The first is simple Numpy [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). The second is [`numpy.max`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.max.html)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 4])
b = np.array([1, 4, 1, 1])

print(np.max(a * b)) # Prints 4
```

If you want the *index* of the maximum value (or, more precisely, the *first* maximum value, since there are two in your example), you can use [`numpy.argmax`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html#numpy.argmax)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 4])
b = np.array([1, 4, 1, 1])

print(np.argmax(a * b)) # Prints 1
```

Comment: I don't think this is what they're asking for. I think they want to find the largest possible sum of products, depending on which elements of `a` are multiplied by which elements of `b`. (In this case, I believe it would be 1 + 1 + 1 + 16 = 19.)